# Boost shared_ptr in ptr_list

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to C++ and quickly began using the boost library, since it offers a lot of functionality I need. Especially the `BOOST_FOREACH` is very useful to me so I can easily iterate through a boost `ptr_list`. Eventually I needed to use another library, which uses boosts `shared_ptr`.

Here is my code:

```
bool SdfParser::parseDataStructure(sdf::ElementPtr sdfRoot)
{
    /* sdfRoot is the root of a xml-like data structure. The first child is "world" and the childs of "world" are several "model" elements */

    nddlgen::models::Workspace* workspace = new nddlgen::models::Workspace();
    workspace->setName("workspace");

    this->_armModel->setWorkspace(workspace);

    sdf::ElementPtr workspaceElement = sdfRoot->GetElement("world");
    sdf::ElementPtr currentModelElement = workspaceElement->GetElement("model");

    nddlgen::types::ModelList models;

    // The sdf lib only offers a useless data structure for the models, so it is
    // converted into a ModelList here
    while (currentModelElement != nullptr)
    {
        models.push_back(&currentModelElement);

        // Iterate
        currentModelElement = currentModelElement->GetNextElement("model");
    }

    if (!this->instantiateModels(models))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!this->calculateDependencies(models))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Explanation:

- `nddlgen::` is the namespace of my work
- `sdf::` is the namespace of the lib I need
- `nddlgen::types::ModelList` is a `typedef` from `boost::ptr_list<sdf::ElementPtr>`
- `sdf::ElementPtr` is a `typedef` from `boost::shared_ptr<sdf::Element>`

Problem:

The code shown here compiles without errors or warnings, but I get the following output when I run the compiled program: `*** Error in './nddl-generator-cli': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffd0ff46460 ***`.

What I tried:

I tried to retrieve the `sdf::Element` from `sdf:ElementPtr` and changed the other code accordingly, but it would not work. I would get some compiler errors. Anyway, I would not like to ignore the libraries suggested use of `sdf::ElementPtr`.

Later I tried to remove the `&` in the argument of the `push_back` function, but this does not compile, of course, since the `push_back` function requires a pointer.

Also I dont wan't to go without boost's `BOOST_FOREACH`, so I also don't want to use any other type of list.

How can it be that boosts `ptr_list` does not work with boosts `shared_ptr`? What can I do to use `sdf::ElementPtr` as well as `BOOST_FOREACH`?

[Edit] Solution:

See accepted answers, especially comments. The trick was to use `std::list` instead of boosts `ptr_list`, since `BOOST_FOREACH` also accepts those.

Comment: Boost Pointer Containers _explicitly_ own their elements. Consequently there cannot be shared ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very strange that you already use `shared_ptr` for `currentModelElement`, and but put the address of that `shared_ptr` in ptr_list. You should put `shared_ptr` in a normal `list`.

And when you put `&currentModelElement` in `ptr_list`, all the element in `ptr_list` are actually the same. They all point to the address of a local variable which is a `shared_ptr`, when ptr_list' destructor is called, the same shared_ptr pointer is deleted several times.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use `shared_ptr` for `currentModelElement`, because thats the way the library I use handles it. Also, I don't think that its always the same address, is it? Because I am iterating them with `currentModelElement = currentModelElement->GetNextElement("model");` in the while loop. That's also the way the library wants one to handle it...

Comment: it's always the same address, the element that `currentModelElement` points to changes after  `currentModelElement = currentModelElement->GetNextElement("model");`, but the address of `currentModelElement` itself never changes.

Comment: Ohhh now I see! Thanks, I wasn't thinking about that. So, if `currentModelElement` is of boosts type `shared_ptr`, can I then just use the `get()` function to retrieve the original address and add those to the (slightly modified) list?

Comment: I don't recommend this way. when you are using shared_ptr, then use shared_ptr everywhere. What you need to do is put shared_ptr in a normal list, not in ptr_list.

Comment: The second flaw you code has is that after `currentModelElement = currentModelElement->GetNextElement("model");` the orignal currentModelElement's reference count is already 0, and the object that shared_ptr points to is already destroyed.

Comment: But if I use a normal `std::list`, then still every item in the list does contain the same element, namely the address of the `shared_ptr`, doesn't it?

Comment: Put `shared_ptr` in `std::list`, not the address of `shared_ptr`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I followed your advice and now it works =) I now just changed the typedef of `nddlgen::types::ModelList` to `std::list<sdf::ElementPtr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Boost Pointer Containers *explicitly* own their elements. Consequently there cannot be shared ownership.

Just store

- shared pointers (`shared_ptr<T>`) in the container (if the container should keep the elements alive)
- weak pointers (`weak_pointer<T>`) in the container (if the container should be able to detect stale elements)
- raw pointers (`T*`) if you know that elements will always live longer than the container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to follow Xiaotian Pei's tipps and it works now. I now store the `shared_ptr` of the library in a `std::list`.

Comment: Which is exactly my option 1. I just wanted to make it much more clear that it's about _ownership semantics_. The name "shared_ptr" should tip you off next time :)

Comment: Ahh now I get it! Thank you for clearing that up for me :)